# setState with spread operator

Tags: reactjs

I was learning Forms in React and I came across the below code where a single setState method is used for multiple inputs to update the value provided by the user. Can anyone explain what spread operator doing here, what does it hold inside the setState method?

```
  class FormContainer extends Component {

  constructor () {

  this.state = {
      formControls: {
          email: {
            value: ''
          },
          name: {
            value: ''
          },
          password: {
            value: ''
          }
      }
  }

}

 changeHandler = event => {

  const name = event.target.name;
  const value = event.target.value;

  this.setState({
    formControls: {
        ...this.state.formControls,
        [name]: {
        ...this.state.formControls[name],
        value
      }
    }
  });
}


  render() {
     return (
      <form>

          <input type="email" 
                 name="email" 
                 value={this.state.formControls.email.value} 
                 onChange={this.changeHandler} 
          />

          <input type="text" 
                 name="name" 
                 value={this.state.formControls.name.value} 
                 onChange={this.changeHandler} 
          />

          <input type="password" 
                 name="password" 
                 value={this.state.formControls.password.value} 
                 onChange={this.changeHandler} 
          />

       </form>      
     );
   }

}

 export default FormContainer;**
```

Source: https://medium.com/@agoiabeladeyemi/the-complete-guide-to-forms-in-react-d2ba93f32825

Comment: it's needed if you want to preserve current values of other fields/inputs ... used to create new state object - requred for detecting updates, decision if rerendering required

Answer (score 0):

It creates a new object with the a key `formControls` and the value for that key is composed of all properties that are in `this.state.formControls` (basically a shallow copy of the old state). The `[name]: {...this.state.formControls[name], value}` part then overrides the key that equals `name` with a new object that is composed of the current properties from `this.state.formControls[name]` and the key `value` overridden with what is in `value`:

```
this.setState({
    formControls: {
        ...this.state.formControls, // shallow copy of current state
        [name]: { // overrides key that equals what is in name
            ...this.state.formControls[name], // shallow copy of current states formControls[name]
            value // overrides value
        }
    }
});
```

Or simply said it sets a copy of the current state, but with the `value` in `state.formControls[name]` changed with what is in `value`, as the new state.

Comment: I understood the first ...this.state.formControls, which is more like the previous state, after that can we not do simply like [name]: value? do we need ...this.state.formControls[name] ?

Comment: something like this -  this.setState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  name: evt.target.value,
}))

Answer (score 0):

setState in React should not mutate state. Instead with help of the spread operator a new object is being created containing the old values and the new [name] property.

Comment: can you tell me what exactly happening here -  [name]: {
            ...this.state.formControls[name],
            value
          }

Comment: In javascript you have two options naming properties in objects: 1. object notation 2. bracket notation. [name] is the second one. Name is the name attribute of the html element.